# How to extend global properties in typescript?

Tags: typescript

**src/window.d.ts**

```
declare namespace NodeJS  {
    interface Global {
        window: {
            location: {};
        };
    }
}
```

In my source code, I am trying to access `global.window.location`. I am getting an error `Property 'window' does not exist on type Global`.

I don't know if the typescript compiler is using my `window.d.ts` or not? How to tell the compiler to use my custom type?

Answer (score 0):

Add this file path to your `files` array of `tsconfig.json`, that way TS will be familiar with it, and extend the real Window object.

BTW, in order to add properties to the global Window object:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    location: {};
  }
}
```